# Send a string on serial port c programming

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

How is it possible on Windows to send a string in C on the serial comport?

```
FILE *port;
    int int_out;
    char buffer[1024];

    if((port=fopen("COM3","w+b"))==NULL){
        printf("Not opened\n");
        }
    else printf("Opened\n");
    char string [] = "test";
    puts(string);
    gets(string);
    printf("Return: %d", string);
```

My code is not sending anything... Why?

Comment: You aren't writing anything to `port` after opening it.

Comment: Note that the `gets` call is very dangerous here! Think about what would happen if you read more than four characters. There's a reason that `gets` have been obsolete for many years, and even removed from the latest C standard.

Comment: simonc tells you what's wrong in his comment, try to think about a solution for it. How do you write to a file opened by `fopen`?

Comment: "port" is a FILE* type. So, now how would you proceed to write with a file pointer? Hint:: You have used "fopen" to open the port. I think something similar is there to write to it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
puts(string);
gets(string);
printf("Return: %d", string);
```

doesn't make any sense whatsover.

You're pointlessly printing the string to standard output, then using a dangerous function to get a new string, which will cause undefined behavior if its longer than 4 characters. Then the new string is printed as an `int`, which is totally bonkers, too.

You should just do `fprintf(port, "%s", string);` to send the string to the newly opened `FILE *` representing the serial port.

Note that you often need to configure serial ports too, fiddly stuff like baud rate, start/stop/parity bits, and so on.